# OverflowMenu codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I am having an issue with my overflowmenu, 
take a look a the pic

[image]

There is a sort of white blocks behind the overflowmenu when it is open

here is the code i have used

```
 tb.addCommandToRightBar(sports);
        mlb=new Command(" BASEBALL",new RR().getR().getImage("mlb.png"));
        nfl=new Command(" FOOTBALL",new RR().getR().getImage("nfl.png"));
        ncaaf=new Command(" NCAAF",f_ncaaf);
        nhl=new Command(" HOCKEY",new RR().getR().getImage("nhl.png"));
        nba=new Command(" BASKETBALL",new RR().getR().getImage("nba.png"));
        ncaab=new Command("NCAAB",f_ncaab);
        tb.addCommandToOverflowMenu(nhl);
        tb.addCommandToOverflowMenu(nba);
        tb.addCommandToOverflowMenu(nfl);
        tb.addCommandToOverflowMenu(mlb);
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens in the simulator and won't happen on the device. It probably won't happen in the simulator either if you enable scroll mode in the simulator menu.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but this is happening in the device itself

Comment: Does it look like that on the device? That looks like a simulator screenshot not a device screenshot. Can you grab a shot from there?

Comment: ON my own device i am using i am not seing this, but the client to who i am developing the app sent me that screnshot, so it is not from the simulator,

Comment: Can you provide details on the device/OS used? It looks like a gingerbread device?